# OutputStream appending file type

Tags: java, android, outputstream

I'm trying to download a file from a server, the server sends me an octet-stream with no extension, however it sends the extension in the http headers (with the name fileType).

What I'm trying to do is read that http header and then append the file type to the downloaded file.

The following code works fine and if I manually add the extension the file is alright:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String fileUrl = params[0];
    String pathToSave = params[1];
    String appId = params[2];
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(fileUrl);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(pathToSave);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
//          String temp = connection.getHeaderField("fileType");
//          byte [] extension = connection.getHeaderField("fileType").getBytes();
//          output.write(extension, 0, extension.length);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Through debug I see that temp is "jpg", so why don't these 3 lines work?

```
//          String temp = connection.getHeaderField("fileType");
//          byte [] extension = connection.getHeaderField("fileType").getBytes();
//          output.write(extension, 0, extension.length);
```

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to append the file type to the content of the file?

If you want to append it to the **file name,** then you need to append it to `pathToSave` and not to the `outputstream`:

```
....
url = new URL(fileUrl);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
String temp = connection.getHeaderField("fileType");
pathToSave = pathToSave + "." + temp;
```

Comment: @Crockes You're welcome. Just a note, temp might be `null` so you might want to protect your code against that by adding an if statement to check wether temp is null or not